# Which public function is called when referenced in superclass constructor?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, overriding

I was wondering about an issue of execution order: if I have a class whose constructor calls a function `f()` of itself and then make a subclass which overrides that function and calls the superclass' constructor, which `f()` is executed?

To answer this question, I wrote this program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Super
{
public:
  Super();

  void
  f();
};

class Sub : public Super
{
public:
  Sub();

  void
  f();
};

Super::Super()
{
  this->f();
}

void
Super::f()
{
  cout << "hello" << endl;
}

Sub::Sub()
  : Super()
{
}

void
Sub::f()
{
  cout << "world" << endl;
}

int
main()
{
  Super super();
  Sub sub();

  sub.f();

  return 0;
}
```

Originally, I did not include the `sub.f()` call in `main()`, but the program did nothing but exit with code `0`, so I added it to test. Now, when I compile with

```
g++ -Wall -o super super.cpp
```

I get this error output:

```
super.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
super.cpp:51:7: error: request for member ‘f’ in ‘sub’, which is of non-class type ‘Sub()’
   sub.f();
       ^
```

Now I'm even more confused. `Sub` is clearly a class type. What have I missed?

Comment: `Sub sub()` is a function declaration.

Comment: When the super-class constructor runs, the object *is* the super-class, so the super-class function would run.

Comment: `Super super();` declares a function, change it to `Super super;`, the same with `Sub sub();`.

Comment: Also, since `f` isn't virtual the superclass one would run anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the super class constructor is running it only sees the part of the object that is the super class. So when the constructor of `Super` runs, it sees the object as an object of type `Super` so it will call `Super::f`.

As for your error, `Sub sub();` declares a function `sub` which returns an object of type `Sub`. What you want is to create an object `sub`. To do this you can declare it like this `Sub sub;` or, if you are using C++11, like this: `Sub sub{};`. The same applies for `Super super();`.